# What's the difference between a Java certificate and a vba certificate?

Tags: java, vba, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I already own a certificate from Verisign for signing Java code. To support a Java application, I have written an Outlook macro and want to sign it. This doesn't work using the Java certificate. Can anyone tell me if:

a) there is a way to use a valid Verisign Java certificate to sign vba code and
b) if not, what is the technical difference that makes certificates language specific.

I only ask as paying the same amount again for another Verisign certificate is a little galling for a handful of lines of vba code.

Comment: Problem solved by using [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) to export the certificate from my Java keystore in p12 format. Therefore separate certificates were not required for my Java, VB6 and VBA applications.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates can have various extensions. The most common one for code signing is quite generic. However, it seems that some platforms require specific extensions.

Some certificate vendors like you to buy one certificate for each platform. I guess they specically don't include some needed extensions. Other, it seems, seem to just require one certificate to sign for multiple platforms: https://secure.ksoftware.net/code_signing.html